# Zoom out of a TableView?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

If you look at the bottom right of Excel you will see a zoom slider. This enables you to zoom out of the grid you are looking at adding more rows and columns to the view.

I would like to be able to do the same in JavaFX using a TableView. I thought it could just be a case of using the scale methods on the TableView (as the code below tries) but this doesn't work. The TableView is made smaller but it doesn't expand to show more rows and columns.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewZoomTest  extends Application {
    private double scale = 0.8;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        TableView<String> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<String, String> tableColumn1 = new TableColumn<>("Column 1");
        tableColumn1.setCellValueFactory(stringStringCellDataFeatures -> new SimpleStringProperty("Hello"));
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(tableColumn1);
        tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello"));

        Button zoomButton = new Button("Zoom");
        zoomButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            tableView.setScaleX(scale);
            tableView.setScaleY(scale);
            scale -= 0.2;
            if (scale < 0.2) {
                scale = 1.0;
            }
        });

        pane.add(tableView, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        pane.add(zoomButton, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        pane.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
        RowConstraints row1Constraints = new RowConstraints();
        row1Constraints.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        RowConstraints row2Constraints = new RowConstraints();
        pane.getRowConstraints().addAll(row1Constraints, row2Constraints);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Take a look at https://gist.github.com/RupprechJo/7455537 , you mind find a solution.